# Count how many options a user chooses from multple selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say i've got 5 selects in an html form but you can only choose options from 3 of them. I need to accomplish the following: 1. calculate a total price, 2. dynamically pass set variables (that will eventually get passed to json for PHP) equal to the name attr of the selected options.

The problem i'm having is that i'm using value ="1" on every option. Then defining the price which is updated each time they select another option by statically assigning the variable with an if else. In what i'm doing each select has many options to choose from.

Where i'm stuck:
Either i'm going to use the name attribute and pass over 5 variables (using option:selected) or there is a way to accomplish this so my database only needs 3 columns to store to the database instead of 5.

I was hoping to accomplish this in the script on the page, rather than in the PHP. Can you do this dynamically and only send over 3 variables for JSON to pass off to the php or is this just going to be easier and faster to send over 5? Yes i'm very new to javascript and jquery :)

```
<form id = "testform" name = "testform" method="POST" action="test.php">
<select class = "choose" id="choice1">
  <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  <option value="1"> Choice 1.a</option>
</select>

<select class = "choose" id="choice2">
    <option value="0" selected=""></option>
    <option value="1"> Choice 1.b</option>
</select>

<select class = "choose" id="choice3">
  <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  <option value="1"> Choice 1.c</option>
</select>

<select class = "choose" id="choice4">
  <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  <option value="1"> Choice 1.d</option>
</select>

<select class = "choose" id="choice5">
  <option value="0" selected=""></option>
  <option value="1"> Choice 1.b</option>
</select>

<label><h4>Total:$</h4> <input style="" type="number" class="num" name="amount" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" /></label>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('select').change(function(){
    var form = this.form;
        var sum = 0;
        var price;      

    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    }); 

if (sum > 3) {
        alert("You can only choose 3 classes");
        $('select.choose').each(function() {
            $('.choose').val(0);
        });
    }
        if (sum == 1){
    price = 80;
    }
else if (sum == 2) {
    price = 130;
}
else if (sum == 3) {
    price = 180;
}

$(".num").val(price);

form.elements['total'] = price;

});
```

Comment: So, check how many selects have a value of something other than `0`, make sure it's not more than 3, then get the name of those selects ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6ajekmx9/

Comment: YES! I went ahead and assigned each initial option a name ="NULL" and changed the js to just pull all of them. that solved my problem of being able to calculate a total AND give the correct info to JSON for the PHP post variables.
You're solution is much better... shorter, and cleaner.  I'm still learning though.

Comment: I can't mark your comment as the answer...

Comment: I can post it as an answer you can accept !

Answer (score 0):

Check how many selects have a value of something other than 0, make sure it's not more than 3, then get the name of those selects

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $('select').filter(function() {
            return parseInt(this.value, 10) !== 0;
        }),
        sum      = selected.length,
        price    = [80, 130, 180][sum - 1],
        names    = selected.map(function() {
            return this.id; // selects don't seem to have names ?
        }).get();

    if (sum > 3) {
        alert("You can only choose 3 classes");
    } else {
        $('.num').val(price);
    }

    console.log(names, sum)

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ajekmx9/)